# CMake - How do I configure a library so that the projects which depend upon it do not need to know about the projects upon which it depends?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have Project A, a library, and Project B, an executable which depends on A.  A and B are completely separate with regard to directory structure, build systems, etc.  A depends on a third party library, X.  As it happens in my case, A, B, and X all use CMake, but A is the only project under my control.  How can I configure CMake for A so that B does not need to know about X?

For the moment, B gets a linker error, and the only way that I can find to make that go away is to have B reference X, which I don't want to do.  I have created a minimal example which recreates my problem.  X happens to be an open source project called pugixml.

Here is file CMakeLists.txt for A:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(projA)

add_library(projA proja.cpp proja.hpp)
target_include_directories(projA PUBLIC pugixml-1.12/src)
target_link_directories(projA PUBLIC pugixml-1.12/build/Debug)
target_link_libraries(projA PUBLIC pugixml)

add_executable(projATest projatest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(projATest PRIVATE projA)
```

I can provide the C++ code if you want, projatest.cpp is just a copy of some example pugixml code.  This compiles and links fine and the tests run and pass.  Interestingly, projATest knows nothing about pugixml.

Here is file CMakeLists.txt for B:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(projB)

add_executable(projB projb.cpp)
target_include_directories(projB PRIVATE C:/projects/pugixml/projA)
target_link_directories(projB PRIVATE C:/projects/pugixml/projA/build/Debug)
target_link_libraries(projB PRIVATE projA)
```

Under visual studio, compilation fails with "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" relating to pugixml.

How can I configure the CMake file for Project A such that Project B does not need to know about pugixml?

**Edit**: Many thanks to those who have commented.  Here are my responses to the comments received to date:

@RoQuOTriX:

> This really depends if library A and X are statically or dynamically linked

I want to build X as a static library, A as a static library which is statically linked to X, and B as an exe which is statically linked to A but does not need to link to X.

@fabian:

> "Interestingly, projATest knows nothing about pugixml." target_link_libraries(projA PUBLIC pugixml) and target_link_libraries(projATest PRIVATE projA) tell a different story...

My point is that projATest and projB contain the same source code and link to A in the exact same way:

```
add_executable(projATest projatest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(projATest PRIVATE projA)

add_executable(projB projb.cpp)
target_link_libraries(projB PRIVATE projA)
```

projATest builds, links, and executes as I would expect.  projB fails to link.  Because projATest is in the same CMakeLists.txt file as projA, CMake is doing something magical to projATest to allow it to link against projA only and not X (pugixml).

@SpacePotatoes:

> if A is static and depends on X, X must be somewhere on the build machine of B developers.

This is not true.  It is entirely possible to create a static library A, which statically links from X the symbols that it requires, such that downstream projects depend only on A and not on X.

Comment: This really depends if library A and X are statically or dynamically linked

Comment: *"Interestingly, projATest knows nothing about pugixml."* `target_link_libraries(projA PUBLIC pugixml)` and `target_link_libraries(projATest PRIVATE projA)` tell a different story...

Comment: In A, export a CMake config file, so that developers of B can rely on it in their project. If properly created, it will provide an imported target carrying transitive dependencies information. Anyway, if A is static and depends on X, X must be somewhere on the build machine of B developers.

Comment: I edited my original post to respond to all comments received to date.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the behavior that I am looking for is not supported by cmake:

[New library type (design discussion)](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22679)

> (for a long time already) I want to implement the new library type (or
> any other) way to do the following:
>
> GNU ar (with MRI file), as well as MS librarian (lib.exe), could
> combine several static libs into a single one. Nowadays few of my
> projects use custom targets but native CMake support for this can give
> more flexibility (like exporting, using the result for further
> target_link_libraries by name/alias, &etc.).
>
> It should produce a static library that includes all other static libs
> (or OBJECT libs, or *.o files of the given sources) mentioned in the
> target_link_libraries (ignoring dynamic libs).

**Edit**: We were able to get the behavior that we wanted by doing the following:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET projA POST_BUILD
    COMMAND lib.exe /NOLOGO /OUT:$<TARGET_FILE:projA> $<TARGET_FILE:projA> $<TARGET_FILE:pugixml-static>)
```

This fix links the entirety of pugixml into projA.  We would prefer to link into projA only those symbols from pugixml that projA requires.  This is the native behavior of the linker but I don't know how to achieve it via cmake.